# Check for grouping values in List<string>

Tags: c#

In one of my programs I need to check for the grouping of items in a list. So I have the values in a `List<string>`. Here's an example list (in this order):

Women's
Women's
Women's
Women's
Women's
Men's
Men's
Men's
Men's
Women's

What I want to check for is the grouping of this list. So the Women's at the bottom **shouldn't** be there. That's an incorrect grouping.

I CAN'T sort this list because there will be a specific order for this that isn't simple like the list above(and can have way more than just 2 different values) and always varies. However, **grouping** will still have to be maintained.

All I want to do is find the incorrect grouping and display an error. I'm hoping there's a better way to do this than looping like crazy. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more context and a an example of data to start and the outcome of the data to get a better answer.

Comment: @Bauss What? `List<T>` has indices for each item. It's not unordered.

Comment: As I understand you want to sort list, so you can use `List<string> list  =list.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();`

Comment: What I'm saying is I don't want to change the order of the list. Only check and display and error. Wouldn't I need to know specific values to do a group by and the list will always be variable.

Comment: @HareshAmbaliya so that would reorder the list(which I don't really want to do), but how does the predicate q => q change the list above?

Comment: @deathismyfriend the example data to start is above. There is no outcome of data. Only a check and then display of error message. I just want to check that all the items in the list are correctly grouped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by looping through the items and keeping track of the unique items seen in a `HashSet<string>` and the previous value.

```
string previous = items.FirstOrDefault();
var seen = new HashSet<string>();
seen.Add(previous);

for (int i = 1; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    if (previous != items[i])
    {
        if (!seen.Add(items[i]))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This item is not grouped:" + items[i] + " at index " + i);
        }

        previous = items[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: that's exaclty what i would do, no linq, not much overhead

Comment: @George technically `FirstOrDefault` is Linq.

Comment: I thought it when I just wrote , but I thought it would go unnoticed lol

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (string item in list.Distinct())
{
    int startIndex = list.IndexOf(item);
    int endIndex = list.LastIndexOf(item);

    bool notGrouped = Enumerable.Range(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1).Select(index => list[index]).Any(i => i != item);
    if (notGrouped)
    {
        // show message for the current item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
List<string> orgList = .......;
bool ok = orgList.GroupBy(x => x).SelectMany(x => x).SequenceEqual(orgList);
```